# Ubuntu Server as a Proxy?

Tags: server, virtualbox, proxy

So Im using VirtualBox for this. I have 2 VM's, one running Ubuntu Server 16.04 and one running Windows. The Ubuntu Server has 2 adaptors configured, one bridged adaptor and another one connected to an internal network.

The Windows is only connected to the same internal network as Ubuntu's second adaptor.

The problem is getting them to talk to each other. They have different IP's despite being on the same internal network as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzcm5.png

The idea was to have the Ubuntu Server behind an OpenVPN which will make the Windows PC forced to be proxied through Ubuntu and through the OpenVPN.

How can I get them to talk to each other?

Comment: The screenshot shows only one adapter on the Ubuntu machine. Also, please post text as text (formatted as code) not as pictures.

Comment: @AlexP IF you see the Ubuntu side, you see its on Adaptor 2 because Adaptor 1 is bridged. Im showing you both are on the same internal network

Comment: Bridged to what?

Comment: @AlexP My Host Internet. Adaptor 1 is connected to my host internet while adaptor 2 is connected to the internal network

Comment: Please post (as text please) the result of `ip addr show`.

Comment: Had to pastebin it as too long: https://pastebin.com/raw/8GqFbQ8y

Comment: @AlexP https://pastebin.com/raw/8GqFbQ8y

Comment: It appears to me that `enp0s3` is connected to the physical LAN (i.e., it's the bridged adaptor) and `enp0s8` is the adaptor connected to the virtual LAN. Try bringing up `enp0s8` with and IP address in the same subnet as the adaptor of the Windows virtual machine.

Comment: @AlexP Sound like a noob but what are u asking and how?

Comment: `sudo ip addr add 169.254.39.90 dev enp0s8`, `sudo ip link set enp0s8 up`. Then try to ping 169.254.39.85 from the Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set both on same network otherwise they won't be able to talk each other, you can set your windows vm to be in 192.168.1.x network or you can configure dhcp on your ubuntu vm https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dhcp.html so next time you 'connect' windows vm it will get an ip adress.

i hope this help you.

Comment: Dude, look at the picture. They are on the same network! Why do u think I provided that screenshot? Second, I added the sample to the config file (by doing sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf) and then posting that sample at the bottom (without the default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200 since thats provided)

Comment: no they aren't your ubuntu vm is on 192.168.1.x your windows vm is on 169.254.x.x both machines have to be on the same network segment

Comment: except that the 192.168 on my Ubuntu is my BRIDGED. Not my Virtual. Also I changed the Windows to 192.168.1.10

Comment: so as alexP said you need to bring up your enp0s8 interface using another segment on both machines(like 192.168.50.x). use this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic (from Configuring an interface section)